# Incompatible type indicators.IndicatorsView

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to implement net.alexandroid.utils.indicators.IndicatorsView to my project.

in the below code,

```
mIndicatorsView = findViewById(R.id.indicatorsView);
```

I'm getting:

```
Incompatible types. 
Required: indicators.IndicatorsView 
Found: android.view.View
```

error but the related controller is a indicators.IndicatorsView

is there any idea why I'm getting this error?

My XML is:

```
<net.alexandroid.utils.indicators.IndicatorsView
    android:id="@+id/indicatorsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:indicatorSize="20dp"
    app:paddingBetweenIndicators="16dp"


app:numberOfIndicators="10"
app:selectedIndicator="5"/>
```

[image: Screenshot of the error:]

[net.alexandroid.utils.indicators.IndicatorsView link](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6177#!description)

Comment: can you not just look up to the sample https://github.com/Pulimet/Indicators-Library/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/alexandroid/utils/indicator/MainActivity.java and follow the same and ide should help

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to typecast your object here. So add this in your code.

```
   mIndicator=(IndicatorsView)findViewById(R.id.indicatorsView);
```

Comment: Your Most Welcome :) @MareCieco

Answer (score 0):

Typecast your indicaterview object.

```
 IndicatorsView inicator=(IndicatorsView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Typecast and Import Respective Class

Replace

```
mIndicator = findViewById(R.id.indicatorsView);
```

with

```
mIndicator=(IndicatorsView)findViewById(R.id.indicatorsView);
```

**and make sure you have imported the correct class i.e., you have the code similar to the one below in the header of your java file**

```
import net.alexandroid.utils.indicators.IndicatorsView;
```